# Two questions about Simula

Tags: programming-languages

I am looking over Simula language to see how it compares to C++/Smalltalk, and I have two questions that are difficult to find answers to because each time I type in Simula into Google, it gets replaced by "C", "Python", or "Simulation".

1. Was Simula case sensitive?
2. What file extension was used for Simula programs?

Comment: The search term is "Simula 67" or "Simula I".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simula is case-insensitive.
>  => [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula#Classic_Hello_world)

After taking a look at the sample content in Simula from this [piece of documentation](http://staff.um.edu.mt/jskl1/talk.html) (download the ZIP folder to view content), the files are saved with either the `.sim` or the `.pas` extensions.

Comment: Ah my bad, I should have figured to check the zip files to test something like this. Now I know. Thanks for the quick response. Also worth noting even without Wikipedia, the zip file contains samples like SIM3.SIM which is all lowercase, and TESTFOR.SIM which has mixed case.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't be surprised if Simula predates the concept of using part of the filename to tag a file with its content-type.